# Where to find woocommerce hooks original code function?

Tags: woocommerce

I know the wc-template-hooks gives us a list of all the hooks but where do I find the original function code to understand what it does in order to alter it? 
Thank you in advance.
All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the original function code of wc-template-hooks code in below file.

> `plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php`